# Apache wont start with php:ldap

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2003, php, ldap, xampp

I just installed XAMPP 1.7.7 on Windows Server 2003 r2 and enabled the php_ldap extension in php.ini Now, when starting the service, it hangs on 'starting'

Aditional info: Since XAMPP 1.7.5+ is compiled with VC9 in stead of VC6 the modules got changed aswell, I suppose it's a compilation bug that I can't use the php_ldap function.

What can I do to fix this? I don't get any kind of error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run `httpd.exe` from the command line and see that it cannot find `libsasl.dll`.
Copy it from `/php` directory to `/apache/bin`, restart the apache server and enjoy.
Other possible dll's that you might need to copy are `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`

Related read: [Solved PHP LDAP error - Fatal error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect()](http://www.incredium.com/php-ldap-connect-error)

Comment: After turning on LDAP on my Windows 7 local host for a Drupal 7 install and I was getting an arror about missing MSVCR80.dll. Tried a bunch of stuff to get this dll installed with no success. Stumbled on this post and copied libsasl.dll in the apache/bin and voila, problem went away.